# C calculate integers but return a float

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate some integers, and I know that the answer of the calculation will contain decimals, so I have to use double. I have commented where I believe the problem in the code is (//This is where everything goes wrong).

I have tried to typecast the calculation by typing `obs.avgX = (float) (arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5;` but it doesn't work at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    struct Observations
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        double avgX;
        double avgY;
    };

    struct Observations arr[5];
    struct Observations obs;


    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter coordinates for point #%d (x,y): ", i +1);
        scanf("%d, %d", &arr[i].x, &arr[i].y);
    }

    printf("\n\nYou entered:\n");

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Point #%d: %d,%d\n", i, arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    }

    // This is where everything goes wrong
    obs.avgX = (arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5;
    obs.avgY = (arr[0].y + arr[1].y + arr[2].y + arr[3].y + arr[4].y) / 5;

    printf("Average of X: %.2f\n", obs.avgX);
    printf("Average of Y: %.2f", obs.avgY);


    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
obs.avgX = (arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5;
```

is doing integer arithmetic

You need to force it to use floating point numbers

i.e.

```
obs.avgX = (float)(arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5.0f;
```

Comment: Okay, but do I really have to use **(float)**? It works like a sharm just by using **5.0f**.

Comment: I am an explicit kinda guy - So the Judge told me

Comment: Hmm, yeah maybe it's better to type (float) too for the visual, but maybe it's a bad idea for performance?

Comment: @user2971623 - Why should it be bad for performance? The compiler has to change the nominator into a float. Mr optimiser is in the wings...

Comment: There is more characters to read, so the program will take longer to compile. I don't know, just a thought.

Comment: @user2971623 - Woh- In such a hurry over 7 characters. Why not change `arr` to `a` That will save ten characters.

Comment: I was more thinking about future programs that may be a lot longer. (float) seems to be very unnecessary in terms of optimization.

Comment: @user2971623 - Where are you getting this from. Write code that is readable and understandable. Somebody at a later date may need to fix the stuff you wrote so be explicit. So you worry about 7 characters here and there but miss the bigger picture

Comment: No, I agree with you. Explicity is important but I was just wondering how (float) affects the performance.

Comment: `(float)` and `5.0f` is _not_ the best type to use here.  Typical `float` will round large 32-bit `int` and OP's result is `double` anyways.  Suggest instead to use `double` and `5.0`.  I guess its a trade-off between accuracy and speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 obs.avgX = (arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5; should be 

 obs.avgX = (float) (arr[0].x + arr[1].x + arr[2].x + arr[3].x + arr[4].x) / 5
```

Comment: I am playing with coordinates so the comma is intended. And this doesn't work. I must type **... arr[4].x) / 5.0f**.

Comment: @user2971623 you have to mention it in your code ! anyways i have changed it